# How to summon villager with locked trades in Minecraft 1.14, 1.15.2, or 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make villager that has **locked trades**. I would use it in maps, but i have unfinished map for 1.16, and when its done I'm going to make map for 1.14 or 1.15.2 (Not sure for version I'm going to do it).
In the 1.16 map's command block I'm using command:

`summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {PersistenceRequired:1b,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:7,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Coin\"",Lore:["\"Final Game\""]}}},sell:{id:diamond_shovel,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:57}]}},maxUses:10}]},VillagerData:{profession:librarian,level:2,type:plains},NoAi:1,NoGravity:1,Health:1}`

I am going to add more trades, but I'm gonna make 5th trade and upper trades locked when the villager is summoned.

Comment: I don't think you can do this; iirc, trades are generated when the villager levels up.

Answer (score 1):

Villager trades have an NBT tag called **uses** which, when set to the value of **maxUses**, disables the trade.

Comment: I meant that it's first locked, but becomes unlocked in a higher level like for example, a trade is locked when the villager is in the _apprentice_ level, but becomes unlocked when it's in the _Journeyman_ level.